# NoSQL Injection with a simple find_by in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql-injection

I am new to RoR and I have a basic question.

A colleague told me that the following code can cause a NoSQL Injection:

```
User.find_by(username: param[:username])
```

I know that I am not supposed to read directly from param but I still think that the code cannot generate any NoSQL injections. Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you ask what their suggested alternative is?

Comment: What is saying is that because I was using "param" directly, that could have caused an nosqlj.

Comment: Using `param` directly, as opposed to... what? Using `params.permit` or `params.allow` doesn't change the values in any way, it just strips away values you weren't expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colleague is wrong, and should produce a working exploit if he believes this is true.

Providing a hash of key/value pairs to Rail's `find_by` or `where` methods is the intended, secure, and correct way of using those methods. The keys and values are always made safe before being used in a query.

There are certain problems that Rails will *not* protect you from, for example, the value of `params[:username]` could be a gigabyte of text, a `File` object, a nested hash of key/value pairs, etc. but this isn't an "injection" per se. Any special characters that could cause the meaning of the query to be changed will have no effect.